# Why does the upcoming Ranges library not support container initialization from a range?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, c++20

## Introduction

With the upcoming Ranges library, the need to denote a range with two iterators is pretty much gone. For example, instead of

```
if (std::equal(begin(foo), end(foo), begin(bar), end(bar)))
```

we have

```
if (std::ranges::equal(foo, bar))
```

The latter is arguably superior not only because of its conciseness, but also because it prevents the common pitfall of omitting `end(bar)` and welcoming bound errors.

## Problem

How about the following code?

```
std::vector<int> vec{begin(foo), end(foo)};
```

where `foo` is a range. With Ranges, I'd expect simplifying it into

```
std::vector<int> vec{foo};
```

However, I fail to find any mention of it in [[vector]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector) or [[container.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements). Nor does the Ranges library introduce a new set of containers.

Why does the Ranges library not support container initialization from a range? What is the rationale?

Comment: `<rant>`Consistency has never been the highest quality of C++`</rant>`. More seriously any addition is severely analyzed to make sure that it cannot break older things. And as the language itself is extremely rich, not speaking of the standard library...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The goal for C++20 was to get ranges in! There were several hurdles to get over before that could happen, but once those were overcome it's quite probable the committee believed it's best to introduce a workable ranges library that is perhaps not feature complete, instead of no ranges at all.

That is not to say that this feature is undesirable, only that there were just some open questions left regarding it, but it's still in the works (see [p1206](https://wg21.link/p1206)).

If one reads the rationale for revision 1 of the paper, it mentions that adding constructors to the standard containers proved unworkable. Likely because the standard containers have so much retrofitted on their initialization that overload resolution becomes a nightmare.

Comment: Hm... the example in that paper is incorrect. `a` and `b` would both be `vector<int>` today, and no new constructors would change that.