# Will we be able to construct containers with views in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

Ranges are coming to C++ with the C++20 standard version.

My question: Will we be able to construct (existing) standard-library containers with any range? And more importantly, with range views?

For example, will this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto sq = [](int x) { return x * x; };
    std::vector<int> vec { 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> squares { std::ranges::views::transform(vec, sq) };
    for(auto i : squares) { std::cout << i << ' '; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

be a valid program which prints `9 16 25`?

<sub>This [compiles with the ranges-v3 library](https://godbolt.org/z/EAGwYL), for what that's worth.</sub>

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950955/why-does-the-upcoming-ranges-library-not-support-container-initialization-from-a

Comment: Per StoryTeller: apparent duplicate of [Why does the upcoming Ranges library not support container initialization from a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950955/why-does-the-upcoming-ranges-library-not-support-container-initialization-from-a)—but note that ballot resolution may yet change the answer!

Comment: @DavisHerring What could change? [P1206](https://wg21.link/p1206) wasn't considered for 20 to begin with and I don't think there are any NB comments left open here? [P1391](https://wg21.link/p1391) was adopted _without_ the range constructor (despite the misleading example).

Comment: @Barry: LEWG [so forwarded it](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/145) in Kona, but I guess I misinterpreted recent reflector traffic about it.

Comment: @DavisHerring Oh, I missed that it was discussed _twice_ - I scrolled down to the the 4-7 poll and thought that was that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question: Will we be able to construct (existing) standard-library containers with any range? And more importantly, with range views?

No. The only standard library component that is constructible from an arbitrary range that meets the correct criteria is `std::span<T>`.

The direction the standard library will likely go with is the one that range-v3 is also going towards (note that the linked example from range-v3 does compile but warns on a deprecated conversion) - using [a helper](https://wg21.link/p1206) to do conversions for you:

```
std::vector<int> squares =
    std::ranges::views::transform(vec, sq) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>;
```

---

One of the reasons to not go in the direction of range constructors can be seen from the very example you're using:

```
std::vector<int> squares { std::ranges::views::transform(vec, sq) };
```

Consider how different that declaration is from these two:

```
std::vector v { std::ranges::views::transform(vec, sq) };
std::vector w ( std::ranges::views::transform(vec, sq) );
```

`v` would necessarily be a `vector<transform_view<...>>` containing a single `transform_view`, while `w` would be a `vector<int>`.

Moreover, adding more, carefully constrained container constructors to the standard library isn't going to help third-party container types anyway - while a facility like `ranges::to` works perfectly well in all cases.

Comment: The statements initializing `v` and `w` look the same to me. Perhaps you meant to declare `w` as a `vector<int>`. Otherwise, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @EricNiebler Exactly :-) They do _look_ the same. They are not the same.

Comment: So, my program compiles but won't do what I think it does. Ok.

Comment: Can you please explain why `v` and `w` are different? Does it have something to do with how constructor template argument deduction work?

Comment: @Johannes Class template, not constructor template. And yes, it has to do with CTAD and `initializer_list` interaction.

Comment: I hate `std::vector`'s constructors.