# Is it possible to construct a `std::span` from a view in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, std-span

This example program does not compile, because the `transform_view` cannot be converted to a `std::span`:

```cpp
class Foo {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> strings = { "a", "b", "c" };

public:
    std::span<const char*> getStrings() {
        return strings | std::views::transform([](const std::string& str) { return str.c_str(); });
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    auto strings = foo.getStrings();

    for (auto s : strings)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

I know that it is not possible to construct containers (like `std::vector`) yet, however I don't quite understand, why it is not possible to construct a `std::span` from it. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458461/1254352), that stated, that currently the only container that can be constructed from an arbitrary range is `std::span`, so I expected the above example to work.

Is there any way to create a span from a range? Or is there any other way to return a generic view from a method, without using `auto` (which is not allowed for virtual methods)?

Comment: No `std::span` cannot be constructed from an arbitrary range. It is just a simple lightweight viewer over a contiguous range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to construct a `std::span` from a view in C++20?

It is possible to construct a span from any *contiguous range* (of appropriate underlying type). The problem here:

```cpp
std::span<const char*> getStrings() {
    return strings | std::views::transform([](const std::string& str) { return str.c_str(); });
}
```

is that the adapted range you're producing isn't *contiguous*, it's only random access. A `span<char const*>` has to refer to `char const*`s that are contiguous in memory, and that's definitely not going to be the case here. That's why this doesn't work.

But that doesn't mean that *no* adapted ranges can be converted to a `span`. For instance, this would work:

```cpp
std::span<std::string> getStrings() {
    return strings | std::views::take(5);
}
```

Since `views::take` can preserve contiguity (in a way that `transform` cannot, for reasons that hopefully are clear).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How about the second part of my question though? I want to be able to pass a view back to the caller, however my method is actually part of an interface, so it's `virtual` and I cannot do something like `constexpr auto getStrings()`. Do I have to create and return an array or vector in this case?

Comment: @Carsten You could return a `span<string>` in your case, without the transform (which is just better than `span<char const*>` anyway). Otherwise, a `vector` is probably a good bet.

Comment: thanks, I think `span<string>` will do for most cases. I need to get the `const char*` array for some C API, though. However, I think in that case, I will use some conversion helper to facilitate a `vector` that stores the pointers then. Thank you! 

Comment: Question: If I interpreting std::span correctly, it's a non owning data structure. So does returning a std::span created from a temporary not end up really bad?

Comment: @marsl It depends. In `getStrings()` here, the lifetime of the `span` doesn't depend on the lifetime of the temporary that `views::take` provides, it only depends on the lifetime of `strings`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::span` is a pointer and a size. It points into an array (or nowhere). There is no array of `const char *`.

You can't get a `std::span` from a `std::deque` either.